# Phising through frames

Tags: frames, phishing

My .net application uses frames.  Currently there is  phishing that happens through frames.  Is there a way it can be controlled programmatically.  Also, suggest a tool to find such phishing attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Incapsula and we deal with such attempts in several ways, mainly by using different verification methods:

To put it simply, we checking session URL against known attack vectors or/and suspicious parameters.

For example, if a XSS attempt looks something like this:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?search=”‘><iframe src=”http://www.phisingsite.com”
height=”200″ width=”200″></iframe>
```

Then there are all kinds of "suspicious" signs you can point to.(besides the phishngsite.com of course... )

Having said that, I`m not sure how you can implement this yourself since this whole method relies on having a large Pool of Suspicions Signatures/Attack Vectors to be used for cross-verification.

For XSS specifically, URL validation is a good place to start.